# camel file: infinite loop when file failed to be moved to in-process dir

Tags: apache-camel

I am using File2 component to process some file in a directory. But if it fails to move file to 'in-process' directory for whatever reason(maybe no permission), the file will be stuck in the directory and will be processed over and over again and fill up the error log. Setting idempotent=true doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is corrupt you probably want to move it to error folder but when you have a system error, not depeding on the messsage/file, you must decide if you want to move it error folder or just log and fix the system problem.

Because you probably want to move the file when system is ok again.